# How to serve an image along with other information using express api

Tags: android, json, node.js, api, express

I want my express api to serve an image file along with other image information.How to make this work at the same time.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `res.append()` Appends the specified value to the HTTP response header field. If the header is not already set, it creates the header with the specified value. The value parameter can be a string or an array.

`res.attachment('path/to/logo.png');
// Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="logo.png"
// Content-Type: image/png`